# the "min" part of the min/max isnt working - javascript

Tags: javascript, random, syntax, numbers

So Ive got this script to find a random number between two user-typed in values. The "max" part works, the randomly generated number is never higher than the higher number. But the numbers generated are still from 1 to the highest number, not whatever "min" to set to. What am I doing wrong?

Looking at other codes Ive tried the "(max - min + 1) + min" formula but it gave the exact same result as Im having now. And sometimes it didnt register at all. It may be a simple syntax problem Im missing? Other variations end up with the random generated number concencrated with the value of "min" instead of adding the two number values together. For example, between 10 and 20, Ill roll an 8 and it will display "810" in the answer box, instead of 18 like it should be.

```
<script>
function roll_the_dice(){

var minA = document.getElementById('hp_one').value;
var maxA = document.getElementById('hp_two').value;
var rangeA = (minA,maxA);
var resultA = Math.floor(Math.random() * rangeA + 1);
document.getElementById('hp_result').value = resultA;
</script>
```

Comment: Try: `var rangeA = Math.min(minA,maxA);`. Also, use `parseInt` when getting `value` from DOM. Also note that you're missing `}` of the function

Comment: I havent learned about ParseInt yet, how would I go about implementing that?

Comment: See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Doesnt really help me figure out where in the code its supposed to go lol is it something like `var minA = parseInt(document.getElementById('hp_one').value;` ?

Comment: Read my first comment again, I've mentioned where it need to be used.

Comment: !!! that WAS it! I cant believe I got it right! XD Im really bad with syntax lol Thanks you so much!! It works now!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function roll_the_dice() {
    //parseInt to convert string values to Integer
    var minA = parseInt(document.getElementById('hp_one').value);
    var maxA = parseInt(document.getElementById('hp_two').value);
    //Math.min-> returns smallest vale from provided numbers
    var rangeA = Math.min(minA, maxA);
    document.getElementById('hp_result').value = Math.floor(Math.random() * rangeA + 1);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the _radix_ when using `parseInt`

Comment: @Tushar, That is an optional argument I suppose. I dont think we need to mention `base` for this example..

Answer (score 0):

```
var resultA = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxA - minA) + minA);
```

should do it. You are multiplying the output of `Math.random()` with what I believe to be a tuple, and I don't think that's doing what you want it to be doing. Also, as Tushar said, you should be using `parseInt()` on the user inputs, or else you'll be multiplying by strings.